# Smooth of standard metric of unit sphere

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Denote
$$
U^2= \{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \}
$$
$g$ is the induced metric. Under the polar coordinates, $\theta$ is polar angle, $\varphi$ is azimuthal angle, the metric is
$$
g=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\
0 &\sin^2\theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$
As the 3.4 section of Petersen's Riemannian Gemetry (the picture below), since
$$
(\sin^2\theta)'|_{\theta=0}=0  
~~~~~~
(\sin^2\theta)'|_{\theta=\pi}=0  
$$
the $(U^2, g)$ is not smooth. But, obviously, the induced metric of unit sphere is smooth. Where is my mistake ?

> [image]
> [image]

Comment: If I'm reading Petersen's notation correctly, $\sin^{2}\theta$ is $\varphi(t)^{2}$, i.e., $\varphi(t) = \sin t$. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  I think you are right. Thanks.